# Applying a different format at every first page of a chapter using Scrlayer-Scrpage

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage

I decided to learn Scrlayer-Scrpage since I'm using a KOMA-script, but I couldn't replicate the result I had achieved using Fancyhdr.

Here's the one with Fancyhdr:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{my_style}{    
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
}    
\pagestyle{my_style}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\usepackage{etoc}           
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 

\addchap{Copyright}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{hello}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

It has achieved the followings:

1. Using etoc, ToC is not numbered or lined even if it exceeds 1 page.
2. Except the first pages of a chapter, a line is drawn above the contents.

This is my attempt using Scrlayer-Scrpage:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}

\usepackage{etoc}           
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 

\addchap{Copyright}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{hello}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

It does have succeeded in not numbering the ToC, but I couldn't find a way to distinguish the first pages of a chapter. The manual of Scrlayer-Scrpage sometimes lists several options without even telling where to put them, and I couldn't find any solution.

Beside the question above, I also want to know how to change the headmarks in both packages. Fancyhdr prints it as Chapter 1. and Scrlayer-Scrpage just as 1.

Comment: The first page is distinguished by default no matter which package or class you use.

Comment: Then what should I do to obtain the same result using scrlayer-scrpage? I guess there should be a way of redefining it like my example did with Fancyhdr, but unlike Fancyhdr's manual, I can't easily locate how to do this in the manual, if at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page style of first page of a chapter of most book classes, distinguishes from the page style of the other pages. Standard class `book` uses hard coded `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the first page of a `\chapter`. KOMA-Script class `scrbook` uses `\thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}` and the default of [`\chapterpagestyle`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.chapterpagestyle) is `plain` too.

And if you have a look at the result of your `scrlayer-scrpage` example:

[image: two pages with the example from the question]

there are several differences between the first page of the chapter (left side) and other pages (right side):

- no head separation line/rule on first page vs. head separation line/rule in other pages
- no running head on first page vs. running head on other pages
- no page number on first page vs. page number on other pages

This first is, because option [`headsepline`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.option.headsepline) does not set a head separation rule on page style plain. You could switch it on using [`plainheadsepline`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.option.plainheadsepline). But I think, you do not want it. So this is good

The second is, because you have removed the defaults for page style [`scrheadings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.pagestyle.scrheadings) and [`plain.scrheadings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.pagestyle.plain.scrheadings) (which is the same like `plain` after the `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`, that is done while loading `scrlayer-scrpage`) using [`\clearpairofpagestyls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage-experts.clearpairofpagestyles) and you've added `\headmark` only to `scrheadings` but not to `plain.scrheadings`. That is absolutely correct.

The third has almost the same reason as the second, but you've added `\pagemark` only to `scrheadings`. So if you like to have a page number on the first page of a chapter, you have to add `\pagemark` to `plain.scrheadings`. This could be done replacing [`\ihead`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.cmd.ihead) by [`\ihead*`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.cmd.ihead*). But this would add the page number to the head. I think, you want the page number at the middle of the foot. So you have to use

```
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
```

Note, the optional argument of [`\cfoot`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.cmd.cfoot) etc. does change the corresponding element of the plain page style.

So with:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}

\usepackage{etoc}           
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 

\addchap{Copyright}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{hello}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

You will get

[image: two pages with page number on first chapter page]

You could even remove using `etoc` and use [`\BeforeStartingTOC`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:tocbasic.cmd.BeforeStartingTOC) and [`\AfterStartingTOC`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:tocbasic.cmd.AfterStartingTOC) to set the first page of the table of contents using page style `empty` but the rest of the table of contents with page style `plain`:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}

\BeforeStartingTOC{\pagestyle{plain}\thispagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Copyright}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{hello}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

BTW: Your `fancyhdr` definition distinguish from your description. It does also set a separation line on the `plain` pages. I would not recommend this, but you can do it:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany, headsepline,footlines=1]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}

\BeforeStartingTOC{\pagestyle{plain}\thispagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{plain.scrheadings}{% whenever page style plain.scrheadings is selected
  onselect={\KOMAoptions{footsepline}}% activate footsepline
}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{% whenever page style scrheadings is selected
  onselect={\KOMAoptions{footsepline=false}}% deactivate footsepline
}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Copyright}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{hello}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I've used [`\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer.cmd.AddToLayerPageStyleOptions) to set KOMA-Script option [`footsepline`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.option.footsepline) depending on the [selected page style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#table.17.2)

If you also want to have upper case running head see option [`markcase`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.option.markcase) in the KOMA-Script manual. If you want the prefix `CHAPTER` see [`\chaptermarkformat`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.chaptermarkformat). If you want to change the font, see elements [`pageheadfoot`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.fontelement.pageheadfoot), [`pagehead`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.fontelement.pagehead), [`pagenumber`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.fontelement.pagenumber) and commands [`\setkomafont`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.cmd.setkomafont) and [`\addtokomafont`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlayer-scrpage.cmd.addtokomafont).

Comment: I've added some direct links to the KOMA-Script manual. I know, that only some Browsers (e.g. Firefox with `pdf.js`) can jump directly to the relative destination in the PDF. User of other browsers or PDF-Viewers will only see the PDF and have to search the corresponding destination on their own.